# How to efficiently make repeated queries for latest key in group?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have terabytes of data organized in an "event sourcing" style. Every update to a key is stored with the "time" of the update, called level. The inner query finds the latest value for all keys at or before a specific time. Then the outer query selects a specific key.

I'm going to run this query 100s of times for a specific time (often in the past), but for many keys. **Is there a way to cache the inner query so only the outer query is run repeatedly?** Or is there a better way to write this query?

```
select value from storage 
where lvl = (select max(lvl) from storage as s1 
              where s1.key = storage.key and s1.lvl <= 4)
and key = 'd';
```

Here's the table:

```
LVL   KEY  VALUE
1     a    10
1     b    11
1     c    12
1     d    13
2     a    20
2     b    21
3     c    32
4     b    41
```

And the table:

```
create table storage (
    lvl integer,
    key text,
    value text,
    primary key (key, lvl)
) ;
```

Comment: I was going to write an answer using an auxiliary table to store these cached values and a user-defined function to either select from that table or select the value the slow way and insert into the table, but I realized I don't know the UDF syntax enough for that. That's what I'd try, anyway. I don't think there's a documented way to do this with something like `ON CONFLICT` that avoids running the costly subquery.

Comment: There is no `time` column in your table example. BTW: `time` is a reserved word (data type).

Comment: I'll fix my example to remove "time". The real query uses terminology that would confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions are:

```
--Using CTE to create a temporary table max_storage 
WITH max_storage AS (
    select max(time), key from storage as s1 
              where s1.time <= 4 GROUP BY key
)
SELECT s.value FROM storage s JOIN max_storage m ON (s.time = m.time AND s.key = m.key);

--Simpler solution using DISTINCT ON but not using "cache" as you asked
SELECT DISTINCT ON (key) value FROM storage AS s1 WHERE s1.time <= 4 ORDER BY key, time DESC;
```

Time and key columns are indexed? If not, it may be a good idea to do so. Also **do not use** reserved words in your objects.

More info about `CTE` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and about `DISTINCT ON` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#sql-distinct).

Comment: Can `max_storage` be parameterized with a time value? I can't hard code it, time goes on forever.